# Using EMV Dual interface with MiFare tag for Access Control

Tags: nfc

I want to allow people to use their Banking EMV cards for Access control by placing MiFare tags on top of them.

Some of the EMV cards are dual interface.

Will using both MiFare and NFC result in interference since they operate in the same frequency or are the EMV cards protected from this?

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely, yes. MiFare tags are NFC compliant, that is they *are* NFC tags, just like the banking cards you are talking about. And you should always avoid putting several NFC tags on one same reader.

What I suggest is you use MiFare chips embedded in a custom card.

By the way, that question would belong more to the Electronics Engineering Stackexchange or to Server Fault.